# Why can't I access my activity with the package name?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app A and an app B, I'm trying to open an app B activity from app A, which is not the main activity.

I know there are already lot of answers on this subject, but I can't manage to make any of these work, this is why I'm asking for help.

First here is the "simplified" manifest of the app B (the one that has to be opened) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Vues.CreationSav"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:noHistory="true">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Vues.GestionSav" android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Vues.StatSav" android:noHistory="true">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Vues.ModifierSav" android:noHistory="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:exported="true" >
            <action android:name="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>


        <provider
            android:name=".Donnees.SavDataProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.Donnees.SavDataProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            ></provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The activity I want to open is ModifierSav, so I did put an intent filter inside of it as it is said to do in every tutorial.

Then I've tried these methods in the other app :

Directly calling the intent filter name :

```
   Intent i = new Intent("com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY");
   i.putExtra("CurrentSavID", itemId);
   startActivity(i);
```

Or using a packageManager :

```
public boolean openSavApp(Context ctx, String packageName, long itemId){
    PackageManager manager = ctx.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (i == null) {
        return false;
        //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    }
    i.putExtra("CurrentSavID", itemId);
    ctx.startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

that I tried to call like this

```
openSavApp(getActivity(), "com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY", itemId);
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to be able to open this specific activity from the other app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed `<intent-filter>` tag.

```
<activity android:name=".Vues.ModifierSav" android:noHistory="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:exported="true" >
            <action android:name="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
```

change this to

```
<activity android:name=".Vues.ModifierSav" android:noHistory="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:exported="true" >
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Update:**

you are getting null intent because you are not providing the correct package name here.

you have provide here this package name which you mentioned in manifest tag.

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav" >`

```
public boolean openSavApp(Context ctx, String packageName, long itemId){
    PackageManager manager = ctx.getPackageManager();
    Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (i == null) {
        return false;
        //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    }
    i.putExtra("CurrentSavID", itemId);
    ctx.startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow I always make the dumbest mistakes...Well thanks a lot for the help

Comment: But when I call openSavApp(getActivity(), "com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY", itemId); my intent is still null, even with the intent filter

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer what you want to do by calling `openSavApp(getActivity(), "com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY", itemId);` method? you want to relaunch the app?

Comment: I want to open the app B from the app A, it works with the first method (where I just use the intent) but doesn't work with a packageManager, and I was just curious why but it doesn't matter much since I've found my way out

Answer (score 2):

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.rlaville.gestionsav.MODIFY_ACTIVITY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

You've forgot to put action and category inside `intent-filter` block.